# Help With A Term In Katakana

Tags: katakana

I came across the following phrase and have been struggling to find what part of it is meant to be in reference to:

> エルアディーナーの壁画

壁画 is obviously just for a fresco/painting but I've been unable to find what エルアディーナー is meant to be. For full context it's about a coat at a fashion show, and the full sentence reads:

> エルアディーナーの壁画をヒントに従来のコートをマキシム調に。。。

Comment: Do you mean, you have no context at all? You have no idea whether this is a place name or a person name?

Comment: It's being used to describe a coat at a fashion show, the full sentence reads:  "エルアディーナーの壁画をヒントに従来のコートをマキシム調に。。。" .

Comment: @Lost-A-Lot Is original text using "。。。" too? I mean, the correct ellipsis in Japanese is "…". If you copied the text from somewhere on the web, a link to the source would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

just doing a basic search: ディーナー means diner, taken from English. It's about a restaurant called Elua (or whatever similar sounding word)

Comment: Dinner and diner have different katakana. ディーナー is dinner, not diner.

Comment: So, by that translation and the context of it being directed at a coat, could it mean "Formal Dinner Jacket"?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have been a misspelling. ディーナー could be "dinner" but dinner is ディナー. They may have meant to say ダイナー as there is a place called "Elua Diner Kobe" in Kobe, Japan, which would make the phrase "A mural of Elua Diner".